# SQL Server Management Studio: icon meaning

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I'm just wondering what this icon means in SQL Server 2008 Management Studio (between the minus sign and the database icon with a green arrow).

[image: Screenshot]

The DB engine is just working as expected. SQL Server Agent is running as well.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe that the icon refers to an alert generated by [Policy Based Management for SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510667.aspx)

Comment: Quite possible, will check that. I'm just wondering why I could not find anything about that in BOL. It's hard to query for a picture with no tooltips... Thanks!

Comment: @S.E.: Documentation relating to the descriptions of icons within SSMS was requested (via MS Connect I think) however was closed/rejected due to insufficient resources.

Comment: I was checking it and really - I did have a policy which was violated. Once I eliminated this state, the icon disappeared.  Thanks for your valuable answer.