# Icons in 2014 SSMS

Tags: sql-server, ssms-2014

I am seeing a icon with a red X in SQL Server Management Studio 2014.  Any idea what it means? [image]

Comment: Duplicate of http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7866/meaning-of-ssms-database-icon-preceded-by-scroll-with-red-x

Comment: and that question links back to [This SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5896910/sql-server-management-studio-icon-meaning)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server Management Studio: icon meaning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5896910/sql-server-management-studio-icon-meaning)

Answer (score 0):

One of the policies I have set up had failed.  Once the policy check ran ok the warning icon went away.